# Getting multiple images from android app error

Tags: php, image, api

I am trying to get multiple images from android app but problem is that when from app there will be 5 images to get from app but when app sends me some images null other images also getting null.but from app if all images is send to server it uploaded successfully. problem is that some images is null then it can not be upload in database. here is my code

i have tried following code

```
If(isset($_FILES['image1']) && $_FILES['image1']['error'] == 0)
                {

                    $path = APPPATH."../uploads/classified/posts/1image".$id;

                    $temp = explode(".",$_FILES['image1']['name']);

                    $extension = end($temp);

                    $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],$path.".".$extension);

                    $image1 = "1image".$id.".".$extension;

                    $flag = $this->Custom_model->update_query("1classified_post",array("image1"=>$image1), array("classified_id"=>$id));                                      

                }
If(isset($_FILES['image2']) && $_FILES['image2']['error'] == 0)
                {

                    $path = APPPATH."../uploads/classified/posts/2image".$id;

                    $temp = explode(".",$_FILES['image2']['name']);

                    $extension = end($temp);

                    $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$path.".".$extension);

                    $image3 = "2image".$id.".".$extension;

                    $flag = $this->Custom_model->update_query("1classified_post",array("image2"=>$image2), array("classified_id"=>$id));                                      

                }
 If(isset($_FILES['image3']) && $_FILES['image3']['error'] == 0)
                {

                    $path = APPPATH."../uploads/classified/posts/3image".$id;

                    $temp = explode(".",$_FILES['image3']['name']);

                    $extension = end($temp);

                    $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'],$path.".".$extension);

                    $image3 = "3image".$id.".".$extension;

                    $flag = $this->Custom_model->update_query("1classified_post",array("image3"=>$image3), array("classified_id"=>$id));                                      

                }
```

Comment: _“but when app sends me some images null”_ - and that means what, _exactly_? Have you checked what $_FILES actually contains in such a case?

Comment: it gives me empty response.from app if there is no images means parameter like image1==null and image2 contains image. but in that case image can not be saved to server if image1 and image2 both contains image it saves successfully

Comment: So what does $_FILES actually contain? Go check!

Comment: it gives empty in this case

Comment: You mean $_FILES is _completely_ empty, just an empty array with nothing whatsoever in it? Then your android app doesn’t seem to be sending this in a proper format that PHP can understand to begin with.